# How do you display text on different lines within a Sharepoint forms header using JSON?

Tags: list, json, header

I am attempting to recreate a word document type form on Sharepoint.

I have been successful in creating a list and formatting the body of the form to a level where questions are in the appropriate section.

The issue that I am encountering is formatting some text in the header. I cannot seem to find any information on how to structure the JSON so that written information for the form can be within the header. I can display the written information in the header but it displays in horizontal divisions.

I would like to display the written information so that it appears under each sentence like it would in the original word document.

Here is the JSON that I am currently trying to manipulate

```
{
"debugMode": true,
"elmType": "div",
"attributes": {
    "class": "ms-borderColor-neutralTertiary"
},
"style": {
    "width": "100%",
    "border-top-width": "0px",
    "border-bottom-width": "1px",
    "border-left-width": "0px",
    "border-right-width": "0px",
    "border-style": "solid",
    "margin-bottom": "16px",
    "column-count": "1"
},
"children": [
    {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
            "display": "flex",
            "box-sizing": "border-box",
            "align-items": "center"
        },
        "children": [
            {
                "elmType": "div",
                "attributes": {
                    "class": "ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontWeight-regular ms-fontColor-themePrimary",
                    "title": "Details"
                },
                "style": {
                    "width": "100%",
                    "flex": "none",
                    "padding": "0px",
                    "padding-left": "0px",
                    "height": "0px",
                    "column-count": "1"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
            "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontSize-24"
        },
        "style": {
            "box-sizing": "border-box",
            "width": "100%",
            "text-align": "left",
            "padding": "21px 12px",
            "overflow": "hidden",
            "column-count": "1"
        },
        "children": [
            {
                "elmType": "div",
                "txtContent": "Request Form"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
            "class": "ms-fontColor-red Secondary ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontSize-12"
        },
        "style": {
            "box-sizing": "border-box",
            "width": "100%",
            "text-align": "left",
            "padding": "21px 12px",
            "overflow": "hidden"
        },
        "children": [
            {
                "elmType": "div",
                "txtContent": "Please ensure that agreement has been obtained from the ‘Business Sponsor’ before submitting this request "
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
            "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontSize-12"
        },
        "style": {
            "box-sizing": "border-box",
            "width": "100%",
            "text-align": "left",
            "padding": "21px 12px",
            "overflow": "hidden"
        },
        "children": [
            {
                "elmType": "div",
                "txtContent": "Please provide adequate information below to enable pre-investigation to be undertaken."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
            "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontSize-12"
        },
        "style": {
            "box-sizing": "border-box",
            "width": "100%",
            "text-align": "left",
            "padding": "21px 12px",
            "overflow": "hidden"
        },
        "children": [
            {
                "elmType": "div",
                "txtContent": "The Team will allocate a Project ID No.  which shall be used to track the progress of this request. "
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
            "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontSize-12"
        },
        "style": {
            "box-sizing": "border-box",
            "width": "100%",
            "text-align": "left",
            "padding": "21px 12px",
            "overflow": "hidden"
        },
        "children": [
            {
                "elmType": "div",
                "txtContent": "This form is only applicable for a request which is not covered by the Catalogue. "
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have searched through many pages on the internet but I don't think my search is optimal as I either end up on the Microsoft documents pages (which provides little information) or other pages regarding JSON Webhooks / API's etc.

[image: Word Document Example]

If someone could please advise whether what I am trying to do is even possible and if so, what I am missing from my code?

Thanks in advance

Rob

Comment: Do you want to create the exact (static) structure like given in above image inside the "header" section of list form?

Comment: Hi Ganesh, Ideally, yes. However, I would be satisfied with just the plain or formatted writing in the header

Comment: Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is kind of old but hoping this helps because there still isn't a lot of documentation on this. In this example, I am using an Office Fabric icon, a header (referencing a field value + static text), and then a note below the header. Hope this helps!

```
{
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
        "class": "ms-borderColor-neutralTertiary"
    },
    "style": {
        "width": "99%",
        "padding-top": "15px",
        "padding-bottom": "15px",
        "background-color": "#9C8DC3",
        "margin-bottom": "16px",
        "display": "flex",
        "flex-wrap":"wrap"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
                "display": "flex",
                "box-sizing": "border-box",
                "align-items": "center",
                "flex-wrap":"wrap"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                        "iconName": "PageHeaderEdit",
                        "class": "ms-fontSize-42 ms-fontWeight-regular ms-fontColor-white",
                        "title": "Details"
                    },
                    "style": {
                        "flex": "none",
                        "padding": "0px",
                        "padding-left": "10px",
                        "height": "36px"
                
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
                "class": "ms-fontColor-white ms-fontWeight-bold ms-fontSize-24"
            },
            "style": {
                "box-sizing": "border-box",
                "width": "60%",
                "text-align": "left",
                "padding-left": "10px",
                "background-color": "#9C8DC3",
                "overflow": "hidden",
                                "flex-wrap":"wrap"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "txtContent": "=[$ListTemplateAction] + ' SharePoint List Template '"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
        "width": "100%",
        "text-align": "left",
        "overflow": "hidden",
        "border-top-width": "1px"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
                "width": "100%",
                "padding-left": "60px",
                "flex-wrap":"wrap"
            },
            "children": [
                {
                    "elmType": "a",
                    "txtContent": "**Master template requests must be approved BEFORE submitting a Change Request**",
                    "attributes": {                       
                        "class": "ms-fontColor-white"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
    ]
}
```